# .htaccess - deny downloading of files

Tags: css, .htaccess, fonts, directory

I keep several fonts in the directory "/fonts/" on my server which I then load into my CSS files via `@font-face`. However, I want to make sure that people cannot download the file just by simply going to `http://www.domain.com/fonts/fontname.ttf`.

Can I somehow prevent this, and still be able to load the font files into my CSS files? Because I think putting `deny from all` into the .htaccess file will even prevent the CSS files for correctly loading the fonts.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: They always can if they send a referrer HTTP-header. You could, however, embed it in your CSS using Base64.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395034/how-to-prevent-deep-linking-to-files-on-my-website/395092#395092. There's no perfect solution though.

Comment: The best option is to **allow people to download the fonts**. Why would you possibly want to prevent this?

Comment: In general, what is seen can be downloaded too in the webs.

Comment: By including the link in your CSS file they already are downloading the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^http://www.yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule   ^/otherdomain/*$ /page-not-found.php
```

Please refer this link

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Relying on referrers or any other user-submitted value is a bad idea

Comment: Referer checking may only be helpful against hotlinking.

Comment: This is likely to break the site for many users. Proxies and certain browsers/extensions strip Referrer. It also isn't hard to spoof referrer. For example, the RefControl browser extension.