# How can I tell a curl request vs browser request

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I have a webserver, and certain users have been retrieving my images using an automated script.I wish to redirect them to a error page or give them an invalid image only if it's a CURL request.

my image resides in `http://example.com/images/AIDd232320233.png`, is there someway I can route it with .htaccess to my controller index function to where I can check if it's an authentic request?

and my other question, how can I check browser headers to distinguish between most likely authentic ones and ones done with a cURL request?

Comment: So aside from your non CURL requests. Are those authenticated in some way?

Comment: You *can* exactly spoof any browser with curl, if you set all the right headers. Then it's impossible to distinguish.

Comment: Generally you can't. What is expected laziness of people trying to download content? (from using stock samples to completely customized queries matching all known browsers)?

Comment: @alexeilvenkov can you provide me an authentic headers example

Comment: Not sure if it's an exact duplicate, but you should check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395034/how-to-prevent-deep-linking-to-files-on-my-website

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the short answer is 'no.'

cURL provides all of the necessary options to "spoof" any browser.  That is to say, more specifically, browsers identify themselves via specific header information, and cURL provides all of the tools to set header data in whatever manner you choose.  So, directly distinguishing two requests from one another is not possible.*

**Without more information*. Common methods to determine if there is a Live Human initiating the traffic are to set cookies during previous steps (attempts to ensure that the request is a natural byproduct of a user being on your website), or using a Captcha and a cookie (validate someone can pass a test).

The simplest is to set a cookie, which will really only ensure that bad programmers don't get through, or programmers who don't want to spend the time to tailor their scraper to your site.

The more tried and true approach is a Captcha, as it requires the user to interact to prove they have blood in their veins.

If the image is not a "download" but more of a piece of a greater whole (say, just an image on your site), a Captcha could be used to validate a human before giving them access to the site as a whole.  Or if it is a download, it would be presented before unlocking the download.

Unfortunately, Captchas are are "a pain," both to set up, and for the end-user.  They don't make a whole lot of sense for general-purpose access, they are a little overboard.

For general-purpose stuff, you can really only throttle IPs, download limits and the like.  And even there, you have nothing you can do if the requests are distributed.  Them's the breaks, really...

Comment: While it can be spoofed, you can at least weed out some curls by checking the user-agent in the headers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750342/how-does-wttr-in-respond-differently-to-browsers-than-it-does-curl/51750402#51750402