# How does wttr.in respond differently to browsers than it does curl?

Tags: curl, browser

If you go to http://wttr.in/ in your browser you'll see a page which is wrapped in a  tag, has links, and is colored using spans.

If you then go to terminal and type `curl http://wttr.in/` you'll get pretty much exactly the same looking page, but the code is very different.

How does wttr.in differentiate between these two?

I'm aware of this existing question ([How can I tell a curl request vs browser request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558888/how-can-i-tell-a-curl-request-vs-browser-request)), but as the answer is "you can't" and I'm seeing proof you can, it seemed like a poor reference.

Also, I'm not worried about spoofing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.  The headers from a default curl contain

> headers: 
>      { host: 'localhost:3000',
>        'user-agent': 'curl/7.54.0',
>        accept: '*/*' },

While the headers from my browser are like so:

> headers: 
>      { host: 'localhost:3000',
>        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0',
>        accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
>        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
>        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
>        connection: 'keep-alive',
>        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
>        'cache-control': 'max-age=0' },

The big difference between the two being the "user-agent" argument

Comment: This answer is the correct one. Please make it as accepted. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

But I believe you can still spoof by setting the user agent with curl command.

Comment: You can.  This is very spoofable, and (as far as I can tell) the only way to avoid such spoofing is lots and lots of surveillance.

Comment: could use captcha