# How to avoid the direct access of images

Tags: php, ajax

I have an images folder,e.g

```
 - www.domain.com/images/1.jpg
 - www.domain.com/images/2.jpg
 - www.domain.com/images/3.jpg
```

I want to show the image when requested by AJAX request else avoid direct access(Browser Address Bar).
How to implement this scenioro.?

**Update**
In a simple way, I want the image to display when requested on my site whether AJAX or any other request. but to avoid direct access to the image if not requested before. For example, I have an image "domain.com/images/myimage.jpg". so the image should not be directly accessible(browser address bar) until the visitor requested through my website frontend.

***Please Note:** Have checked some of these types of real-world examples. I know their images name but when I put the link on the address bar, it shows `Access Denied` until I request from their website, and they are using AJAX request.*

Comment: Ajax requests never _show_ images, they can only retrieve image data or an image url. If they return and image url, the browser has to then make the request to that url to show it which is what you dont want. The only thing I can think of that would work would be to deny access to all image files via htaccess or similar and then in your php, get the file contents and return them to the ajax as a base64 encoded string and have the front end use that.

Comment: as hardillb mentions below, you could filter requests by some header, but note that this approach can be easily bypassed.

Comment: And no option would ever be considered "protecting" the images as once you show it, its game over for protecting it.

Comment: In a simple way, I want the image to display when requested on my site whether AJAX or any other request. but to avoid direct access to the image if not requested before. For example, I have an image "domain.com/images/myimage.jpg". so the image should not be directly accessible(browser address bar) until the visitor requested through my website frontend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395034/how-to-prevent-deep-linking-to-files-on-my-website

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

If an image is displayed on a page there is NO way to stop people being able to download that image, but you can stop people embedding the image in their own site while sill having it served from your site.

There is no need resort to loading images via AJAX.

The simplest way is by filtering access based on the [referrer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

This would mean that images can only be accessed if they are being included in a sites pages (or the client specifically sets the right header)

Comment: In a simple way, I want the image to display when requested on my site whether AJAX or any other request. but to avoid direct access to the image if not requested before. For example, I have an image "domain.com/images/myimage.jpg". so the image should not be directly accessible(browser address bar) until the visitor requested through my website frontend.

Comment: Then referrer based filtering is the solution.